# Repeat user input JMeter

Tags: java, post, web, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to record what I do in my FireFox browser. After, I need to repeat this a few hundred times. I also need to change a part of the data which goes to the server (such as increment a number in the text I POST).

How can I go about doing this in JMeter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to generate incrementing number is using Add > Logic Element > Count and set the counter initial value followed by maximum value also set the reference name.
[image: Check image for counter setup]
You can access the reference name by providing ${reference name} in the request.

**Generating unique random** 
Go to Add > Pre processor > User Parameters
Enter the parameter name which you want to have it unique and assign this method to generate unique number to${__V(${__Random(30002,40000,)})}

If you want to generate unique string, [image: check this attached image]

You can also generate number in incremental order using Bean Shell scripting Add > Pre processor > BeanShell Processor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was excellent thank you. I am still really new to JMeter though, so would you mind also showing me how to do this to the path in RecordingController please? I setup the proxy in the browser, I have a load of paths, when I select the correct one (where the submission happens) what do I do next? Sorry for my poor explanation.